# Unambiguous grammar for expressions with let and addition

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, ambiguous-grammar

What is an unambiguous grammar equivalent to to the following ambiguous grammar for a language of expressions with **let** and **addition**?

E ⇒ let id = E in E

E ⇒ E + E

E ⇒ num

The ambiguity should be solved so that:

- addition is left associative
- addition has higher precedence than let expressions when it appears on the right
- addition has lower precedence than let expressions when it appears on the left

Using braces to show the grouping of sub-expressions, the following illustrates how expressions should be interpreted:

`num + num + num` => `{ num + num } + num`

`let id = num in num + num` => `let id = num in { num + num }`

`num + let id = num in num` => `num + { let id = num in num }`

Answer (score 2):

Consider the expression

`E1 + E2`

`E1` cannot have the form `let ID = E3` because `let ID = E3 + E2` must be parsed as `let ID = (E3 + E2)`. This restriction is recursive: it also cannot have the form `E4 + let ID = E3`.

`E2` can have the form `let ID = E3` but it cannot have the form `E3 + E4` (because `E1 + E3 + E4` must be parsed as `(E1 + E3) + E4`). Only `E1` can have the form `E3 + E4`.

It's straight-forward (but repetitive) to translate these restrictions to BNF:

```
Expr      ⇒ Sum

Sum       ⇒ SumNoLet '+' Atom
          | Atom
SumNoLet  ⇒ SumNoLet '+' AtomNoLet
          | AtomNoLet

AtomNoLet ⇒ num
          | id
          | '(' Expr ')'
Atom      ⇒ AtomNoLet
          | 'let' id '=' Expr
```

To make the pattern clearer, we can add the `*` operator:

```
Expr      ⇒ Sum

Sum       ⇒ SumNoLet '+' Prod
          | Prod
SumNoLet  ⇒ SumNoLet '+' ProdNoLet
          | ProdNoLet

Prod      ⇒ ProdNoLet '*' Atom
          | Atom
ProdNoLet ⇒ ProdNoLet '*' AtomNoLet
          | AtomNoLet

AtomNoLet ⇒ num
          | id
          | '(' Expr ')'
Atom      ⇒ AtomNoLet
          | 'let' id '=' Expr
```

It is possible to implement this in bison (or other similar parser generators) using precedence declarations. But the precedence solution is harder to reason about, and can be confusing to incorporate into more complicated grammars.